# Can't access PHP command in Command Line

Tags: php

I have a problem in accessing the php command using command line.
I also created a PATH in my environment variables.

The PATH is like this

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12

Now the console output is this

```
C:\Users\Web4>php
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also restarted the PC and the command console still same effect. I also created a batch for this still same effect too.

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
```

Is there some configuration other than this? I am using wampserver.

Comment: Check where the `php.exe` is, i guess is in `bin` directory so your path need to be something like this `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\bin`

Comment: It's not in he bin folder. :(

Comment: did you check if that path is actually in system path variable (system->environment variables)? i think setting path with your command works only while cmd is open.

Comment: I saved it in the environment variables.

Comment: and it is in when you type echo %PATH% ?

Comment: If you have enough RAM (say, 256MB unused), you really should just run a non-gui version of linux inside VirtualBox. PHP works on windows but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert i have set up PHP for both Windows and Linux and did not have any problem. Even with server edition virtual mashine slows down computer if you dont have a lot of RAM.

Comment: @Bojan Kovacevic, No it doesn't include my path. :(

Comment: @user3651129 that means you are doing something wrong when setting path. maybe your path is broken? forgot ; between paths?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I've also set it up on windows and linux and mac, hundreds of times. But linux is clearly the native environment, and I always recommend it to new users. Yep, if you don't have enough RAM a virtual machine will slow it down. But RAM is cheap.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert it is interesting to suggest linux (especially server/not GUI) for beginners as it require certain knowledge in setting up user rights, using shell, configuration files and few others concepts beginners usually don’t have. Maybe you mean just PHP (web developer) beginners, but in my experience most of new web developers are also fairly new to linux.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic in my opinion understanding how a server works is a pre-requisit to learning how to write software that will run on a server. You should learn Linux first, then learn PHP. Unless you're going to run your PHP on a windows server... but in that case, I suggest learning .Net instead of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run echo %PATH% and it does not include the path to WAMP, then the problem is simply that you haven't set it properly in your environmental variables.

The setting is located here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcHT9.png

Edit the System Variables "Path" field and prepend your path to WAMP (obviously make sure you have the exact path to the folder where php.exe is located).  Then click OK until all the settings dialogs are closed.

Once you change the path, you will need to close your CMD window and open a new one.  The path changes don't take effect on any open CMD windows.